# why does win.focus() not bring the window to the front?

Tags: windows, electron

In code:

```
function focusOnMainWindow(): void {
  win.focus();
}
```

In practice:
[image: electron]

I want my electron application to appear above other programs. But only the yellow glow from him works! Why?

Comment: Try using `app.focus()` https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/app#appfocusoptions

Comment: @DEVLOPR i tried it doesn't work

Comment: Quote: "You should seek to use the steal option as sparingly as possible".  Yup, on Windows that is enforced.  Rules [are here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-allowsetforegroundwindow#remarks).  Won't help you, use a tray icon to attract attention.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`win.focus()`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/browser-window#winfocus) isn't necessarily designed to bring the window to the front (see [this](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/2867) github issue).

If you want the window to be brought to the front, you'll have to get more creative. The function I have in my app is fairly complex to handle all sorts of edge cases, but maybe something like this will get you started:

```
// maybe you want to handle this case, maybe not
if (win.isMinimized())
    win.restore();

win.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
app.focus();
win.setAlwaysOnTop(false);
```

The idea is adapted from [here](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/2867#issuecomment-409858459). Note in their case, they're doing:

```
win.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
win.show();
win.setAlwaysOnTop(false);
app.focus();
```

Comment: You might still have an issue where the window is brought to the front but isn't focused. If so, I can try to assist - my actual function is a bit more complex than above and solving that might require a more advanced workaround

Comment: 2nd variant thanks!

Comment: but sometimes it doesn't work, please help @pushkin

Comment: it doesn't work if i just open other windows on top of them @pushkin

Comment: it can be a bit inconsistent. I'll take a look at what I did a little later

Comment: so? @pushkin ??

Comment: @Trr seems like I'm also telling an external .net process to force the window to the front through some tricky process. That might not be suitable for you. Bringing windows to the front in Windows is imperfect and can't be expected to work in every scenario

Comment: @Trr there's apparently a `win.moveTop()` method. Maybe try using that as well.

Answer (score 0):

Electron has property of `app.focus()`. But make sure you use it with options like:-

```
app.focus({
   steal: true
});
```